# Earliest Date in a year in multiple years

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to set up a query which returns the earliest date in a year in multiple years.

Ex:

```
06-apr-1990
07-may-1991
03-apr-1992
07-jun-1993
```

the earliest would be `03-apr-1992`

any help is appreciated (-:

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

the dates are in Date format

Comment: Please specify which DBMS you are using.

Comment: What DBMS? Are your dates stored as text (a bad idea but sometimes unavoidable) or as a datetime type?

Comment: **select MIN(your_field) from your_table;** (& it will work on any SQL dbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, try :

```
SELECT TOP(1) date FROM table ORDER BY Month(date), Day(date)
```

For MySQL this should do the trick :

```
SELECT date FROM table ORDER BY Month(date), Day(date) LIMIT 1;
```

For Oracle :

```
SELECT date FROM table ORDER BY Month(date), Day(date) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Comment: Noting that this is SQL Server syntax and won't work on Oraacle or MySQL would certainly hel[ future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

`SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name,column_name ASC|DESC;`

source [w3school.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will get a more positive response if you learn to format your code. You can also earn rep by editing other user's poorly formatted code, until you hit 2K rep.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
create table #temp1
(
 ID INT , 
 CreatedDate datetime
)

INSERT #temp1 (Id, CreatedDate )values(1, '06-apr-1990')
INSERT #temp1 (Id, CreatedDate )values(2, '07-may-1991')
INSERT #temp1 (Id, CreatedDate )values(3, '03-apr-1992')
INSERT #temp1 (Id, CreatedDate )values(4, '07-jun-1993')

SELECT A.CREATEDDATE FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CREATEDDATE, CAST(YEAR(CreatedDate) as char(4)) [YEAR], DATENAME(MONTH,CreatedDate)   [MONTH]
    , DATENAME(DAY,CreatedDate) [DAY]
    FROM #temp1
    GROUP BY CreatedDate
    ORDER BY [DAY], [MONTH], [YEAR]
 ) A
```

Answer (score 0):

[ANSI](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ccb0e/3) SQL, supported on [Oracle 12](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php):

```
select * 
from tbl 
order by extract(month from the_date), extract(day from the_date)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For lower version of Oracle, you can use this:

```
with a as
(
  select 

      row_number() 
          over(order by 
               extract(month from the_date), extract(day from the_date)) as rn, 

      tbl.the_date

  from tbl 
)
select the_date 
from a
where rn = 1;
```

Live Code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6a75/20